# feeding several variables from scala / spark-shell to hive table

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have 4 variables in scala / spark-shell.

```
S1 = (a string) = "age"
S2 = (another string) = "school"
D1 = (a double) = 0.50
D2 = (another double) = 0.75
```

I need to feed this to a hive table like so:

Factor Coeff

age    0.50

school 0.75

I was able to create table from scala/spark-shell:

```
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

//following works

```
hiveContext.sql("create table students_table (factor STRING, coeff FLOAT) stored as orc")
```

However, I am at loss as to how to insert these values to the hive table.

I have played to insert and update statements.
I have also played with data frames.
I have also tried dump the data into text files in hdfs (first turning them into RDDs), but the format came out in such a way that I was unable to then use it as fodder for hive table.

I am sure I am missing the whole idea on how to do this.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val input = sc.parallelize(Array((s1,D1), (s2, D2)))
case class StudentTable(factor : String, coeff : Double)
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df = input.map(x=>StudentTable(x._1, x._2)).toDF
df.saveAsTable("students_table", org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Append)
```

Comment: nput: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Any] = ParallelCollectionRDD[257] at parallelize at <console>:352
defined class StudentTable
<console>:356: error: value _1 is not a member of Any
       val df = input.map(x=>StudentTable(x._1, x._2)).toDF

Comment: I have researched that error , but way over my head. best I can guess its some of sort type mismatch. But both are string :-)

Comment: I edited my answer that was a typo. Can you check again.

Comment: I think it worked, but VM is having memory issues. Rebooting. I will keep you posted

Comment: You should also change datatype of  `(factor STRING, coeff FLOAT)` to `(factor STRING, coeff Double)`

Comment: works like a charm!! Thank you!! Tagging your answer as answer now.